# Python max() argument is said to be empty?

Tags: python

```
arr = map(int, input().split())
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

Here, `max(arr)` is said to be an empty argument. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Once the `map` iterator object is iterated a single time, it is "empty".

Try this:

```py
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

`map` does not return a list.

Answer (score 2):

`map()` returns something like `<map object at 0x026FC9B8>`, which will empty out once the program iterates through it. 
It gives you that error because after using `min()` on the map object, it becomes empty, and so, passing it into `max()` resulted in the error.

To fix it, convert the `map object` to a `list`:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
2
4
```

---

---

An alternative is to use a list comprehension:

```
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split())
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try print array you will see it is not a list its a memory location like this `<map object at 0x7fd087897a34>` because of that first convert it to list

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(max(arr))
```

Comment: Your code without the list conversion will literally still work.

Comment: The issue is not with the type, but because of the number of times OP needs to iterate through it